# Create data frame column that maps 2 keys in a dictionary to same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, hashmap

> I have 2 dictionaries and want to create a new column to map 2 keys to a single value.

*Dict 1*

```
dict1 = 
{
    "A" :[619, 588],

    "B" : [772, 880],

    "C" : [033, 944],

    "D" : [077, 854]
}
```

*Dict 2*

```
dict2 = 
{
    "A" : 600,

    "B" : 680,

    "C" : 300,

    "D" : 100
}
```

> I want to map each ID, by creating a new column 'Name' and then another column that maps the 'Name' the Value

```
ID   Name  Value
619   A     600
588   A     600
772   B     680
880   B     680
033   C     300
944   C     300
077   D     100
854   D     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the values in `dict1` are unique:

```
d = {v: k for k in dict1 for v in dict1[k]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list(d.keys()), 'Name': list(d.values())})
>>> df.assign(Value=df['Name'].map(dict2))
    ID Name  Value
0  619    A    600
1  588    A    600
2  772    B    680
3  880    B    680
4  033    C    300
5  944    C    300
6  077    D    100
7  854    D    100
```

Or:

```
d = {v: k for k in dict1 for v in dict1[k]}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': list(d.keys()), 
    'Name': list(d.values()), 
    'Value': [dict2[val] for val in d.values()]})
```

Comment: @AmoghKatwe you should consider upvoting this answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1_melt=df1.melt(var_name='Name',value_name='ID')
df1_melt['value']=df1_melt.Name.map(dict2)
#df1_melt=df1_melt.set_index('ID') #If you want ID like index 
print(df1_melt)
```

---

**Output**

```
  Name   ID  value
0    A  619    600
1    A  588    600
2    B  772    680
3    B  880    680
4    C  033    300
5    C  944    300
6    D  077    100
7    D  854    100
```

---

note that the values ​​of C and D in dictionary 1 (dict1) must be read as a string because they start with 0

```
dict1 = 
{
    "A" :[619, 588],

    "B" : [772, 880],

    "C" : ['033', '944'],

    "D" : ['077', '854']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange your first dict to a more workable format, then the problem becomes much more straightforward.

```
id_mapper = {x: key for key, value in dict1.items() for x in value}

df = pd.DataFrame(index = [
    "619",
    "588",
    "772",
    "880",
    "033",
    "944",
    "077",
    "854",
])

df['Name'] = df.index.map(id_mapper)
df['Value'] = df['Name'].map(dict2)

>>> df

    ID      Name    Value
0   619     A       600
1   588     A       600
2   772     B       680
3   880     B       680
4   033     C       300
5   944     C       300
6   077     D       100
7   854     D       100
```

For clarity, id_mapper looks like this:

```
{'619': 'A', '588': 'A', '772': 'B', ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension and the constructor.

---

```
pd.DataFrame([
    dict(ID=el, Name=k, Value=dict2.get(k))
    for k, v in dict1.items()
    for el in v
])
```

```
    ID Name  Value
0  619    A    600
1  588    A    600
2  772    B    680
3  880    B    680
4   33    C    300
5  944    C    300
6   77    D    100
7  854    D    100
```

Comment: I think I like this best.  As I try to tailor my answer, I get closer to this one.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([(i, n, dict2[n]) for n, I in dict1.items() for i in I], columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Value'])`

Comment: Yea that's much cleaner with the explicit column names at the end!

Answer (score 1):

#### `toolz.dicttoolz.merge`

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge

d1 = merge(map(dict.fromkeys, dict1.values(), dict1))
s = pd.Series(d1).rename_axis('ID')
pd.concat({'Name': s, 'Value': s.map(dict2)}, axis=1).reset_index()

    ID Name  Value
0  619    A    600
1  588    A    600
2  772    B    680
3  880    B    680
4  033    C    300
5  944    C    300
6  077    D    100
7  854    D    100
```